# error during compilation gr-gsm for GNU Radio 3.8

Tags: linux, build, cmake, ld

I'm trying to compile gr-gsm ( https://github.com/ptrkrysik/gr-gsm ) project. While running cmake I'm occuring following error:

```
.
.
.
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_5223d
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir   /CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_5223d  -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_5223d] Błąd 1
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu '/home/notroot/Pobrane/gr-gsm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_5223d/fast] Błąd 2
```

and after running **/usr/bin/cc -lpthreads** command I also occur this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but not after running **/usr/bin/cc -lpthread** command that produces this output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/9.2.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I managed to replace all **-lpthreads** with **-lpthread** flag with **grep -irl "lpthreads" ./* | xargs sed -i 's/lpthreads/lpthread/g'** command. After running it I see following error:

```
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_5223d
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_5223d  -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_5223d.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_5223d] Błąd 1
make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu '/home/notroot/Pobrane/gr-gsm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_5223d/fast] Błąd 2
```

but while running without cmake ld an find lpthread!

Comment: "While running cmake I'm occuring following error" - It is **not an error** which prevents building the project. It is just a **check** of CMake that your system has `pthreads` library. It will then check for `pthread` library too. After all checks CMake decides which library can be used for POSIX threads functionality. If you have a real error while building the project, show the appropriate part of the **output** of `cmake` invocation. What you show is `CMakeErrorLog.txt` file, and looking into this file has no sense without the main output of `cmake`.

Comment: This is the final part of CMakeError.log

Comment: full log - https://pastebin.com/QNFvpE7p

Comment: When run `cmake` you got the message like `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also «/home/noroot/xcicoin/Pobrane/gr-gsm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log»`, am I right? If you want to handle this problem, then firstly you need to find the **actual error message** which is somewhere **above** the `-- Configure incomplete` line. Without knowing this error message there is no reason to look into `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeError.log` files. Please, show that **actual error message** from `cmake` **output**. Note, that none of files contains this message.

Comment: None of the logs contain such a line. Here they are:
CMakeOutput.log - https://pastebin.com/7jvWDH4h
CMakeError.log - pastebin.com/QNFvpE7p

Comment: No, do not look into the **files**, look into `cmake` **output**. Why do you ever think that building the `gr-gsm` failed? Why do you ever look into the files? Where have you found their names?

Comment: Oh! My mistake! I did not understand you ... I have such a line in the output:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: 150 (message):
   GnuRadio Runtime required to compile gr-gsm

do you know what to do with it?

Comment: Here is this line: if(NOT GNURADIO_RUNTIME_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "GnuRadio Runtime required to compile gr-gsm")

Comment: Nice, so this is an **actual error**. Please, update the question post to reflect it. As "pthread" is completely unrelated to that error, you may remove it from the question post.

Comment: The [wiki page about installation](https://osmocom.org/projects/gr-gsm/wiki/Installation) tells that you need to install "GNU Radio with header files". Have you performed this step? How have you performed it?

Comment: yes, I have libosmocore, gnuradio-osmosdr and gnuradio installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
https://github.com/ptrkrysik/gr-gsm/issues/487

This code did not worked with GNU radio 3.8. Only worked with GNU radio 3.7.